# Gitlab CI service isn't reading 'variables' config

Tags: mysql, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to use a mysql service in my CI jobs but I keep getting connection refused errors.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` config:

```yaml
variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql_test
  MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'

mysql-test:
  stage: test
  needs: []
  image: mysql:8.0.28
  variables:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql_test
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
  services:
    - name: mysql:8.0.28
      alias: mysql
      variables:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql_test
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
  script:
    - echo SELECT 'OK' | mysql mysql_test --host='mysql' --user=root --password=''
```

Despite having set `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD` in 3 different places, the service container logs are giving me:

```
2022-08-14 00:11:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.28-1debian10 started.
2022-08-14 00:11:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-14 00:11:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.28-1debian10 started.
2022-08-14 00:11:04+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
    You need to specify one of the following:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
    - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

GitLab and its runners are on a helm installation (chart gitlab-5.7.0, app version 14.7.0)

Comment: Any chance you have this defined on the project or group variables in CICD settings?

Comment: Nope. Nothing set in the group/project vars

Answer (score 1):

I try to run your script it works. you can look in [mysql-test #2879743403 Jobs](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/gitlab-ci-parallel-test01/-/jobs/2879914101) and  [My Example .gitlab-ci.yml source code](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/gitlab-ci-parallel-test01/-/blob/try-mysql-service/.gitlab-ci.yml)

you should echo Variable in your script to verify variable setting is correct.

```yaml
mysql-test:
  tags:
    - docker
  stage: test
  needs: []
  image: mysql:8.0.28
  variables:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql_test
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
  services:
    - name: mysql:8.0.28
      alias: mysql
  script:
    - echo $MYSQL_DATABASE
    - echo $MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
    - |
      mysql mysql_test --host='mysql' --user=root --password='' <<SQL
      SELECT version();
      exit
      SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

The variables weren't being set property for the services because `services:variables:` is only supported in GitLab runner 14.8 and onward, having the variables set in the job but *not* the service seem to work.

Secondly, the MySQL service takes a minute to load. adding a long enough `sleep` to the script, along with the variables set correctly has it connecting happily.